How can I deploy Next AND Storybook to Vercel
I'm new to Vercel, I've found deploying Next js to be really easy and well documented, as is deploying a Storybook integration. Deploying both together is proving to be a nightmare, I've searched for documentation for this and found nothing.
I've tried coming up with a shared vercel.json combining the individual json files, I've found that slight configuration changes switches from deploying Storybook to deploying Next js and vice versa, but nothing resulted in both being available. I've also tried creating a sub folder with storybook configuration, which built and ran fine locally but not on vercel. I also tried deploying from a subfolder that only had a vercel file in it, this failed all together as apparently its not allowed. I don't mind how I have to do this, short of duplicating my entire project; single/multiple projects, unusual directory structure, whatever, I just want to have both resources available via Vercel.

I've had the issue of trying to run two services at once before, and I solved it using the npm package concurrently, and running the start commands for both servers at once. However, I later regretted it as it turned out to be much simpler to just run two seperate Vercel projects with two different servers; is there any reason why you can't do this?

The issue here is that the code for Next js and Storybook are shared. They are essentially two separate ways of viewing the same markup. Having the storybook specific files in a separate directory structure that references the main Next js project results in dependency errors. But, of course, there can be only one vercel.json file in a given location, and vercel.json doesn't support multiple configurations

@rabbibillclinton, thank you. I got it! I started thinking about the problem differently and realised that Incould set up two projects for the same GitHub but configure them on Vercel's side to use different build configs. It means I'll need to push each time I want to deploy (or create temporary json files) but at least it works

Have you overriding the build command in vercel's settings? Perhaps you can run the build storybook command there. I'm thinking it would server the storybook by running that script then it should be accessible
i.e domainname.com:6006/
Although I'm not entirely sure if this would work
